# r - calculate moving window correlation coefficients between one x and hundreds of y variables, then create a new dataframe of r-values

Tags: r

I would like to calculate 11-year moving window Pearson correlation coefficients between one column of temperature data and the growth many plants (e.g., hundreds to thousands of plants).  Here's a limited example of what the dataframe would look like:

```
dat <- as.data.frame(rbind(c(1945,11.4,0.508,0.160,0.419,0.255), c(1946,12.5,0.065,0.127,0.881,0.541),  
                       c(1947,12.4,0.162,0.142,0.539,0.447), c(1948,12.9,0.274,0.102,0.862,0.728),
                       c(1949,11.1,0.284,0.042,1.863,0.126), c(1950,13.0,0.015,0.109,1.925,0.142),
                       c(1951,13.3,0.001,0.160,1.585,0.245), c(1952,12.2,0.233,0.033,1.199,0.076),
                       c(1953,13.4,0.169,0.123,1.729,0.529), c(1954,12.6,0.135,0.166,1.754,0.171),
                       c(1955,11.7,0.275,0.167,1.389,0.382), c(1956,11.9,0.092,0.032,0.697,0.325),
                       c(1957,13.3,0.054,0.105,1.387,0.178), c(1958,13.4,0.311,0.041,1.585,0.593)))
names(dat)<-c("year", "temp", "plant1", "plant2", "plant3", "plant4")
dat
   year temp plant1 plant2 plant3 plant4
1  1945 11.4  0.508  0.160  0.419  0.255
2  1946 12.5  0.065  0.127  0.881  0.541
3  1947 12.4  0.162  0.142  0.539  0.447
4  1948 12.9  0.274  0.102  0.862  0.728
5  1949 11.1  0.284  0.042  1.863  0.126
6  1950 13.0  0.015  0.109  1.925  0.142
7  1951 13.3  0.001  0.160  1.585  0.245
8  1952 12.2  0.233  0.033  1.199  0.076
9  1953 13.4  0.169  0.123  1.729  0.529
10 1954 12.6  0.135  0.166  1.754  0.171
11 1955 11.7  0.275  0.167  1.389  0.382
12 1956 11.9  0.092  0.032  0.697  0.325
13 1957 13.3  0.054  0.105  1.387  0.178
14 1958 13.4  0.311  0.041  1.585  0.593
```

I recognize that this can probably be done in the running package of gtools.  However, I'm concerned about the output.  I would like to create a dataframe of correlation coefficients that looks like this:

```
dat <- as.data.frame(rbind(c(1950,-0.72,0.22,0.25,0.35), c(1951,-0.55,0.47,0.12,0.33),  
                       c(1952,-0.61,0.43,0.13,0.24), c(1953,-0.39,0.29,0.15,0.36)))
names(dat)<-c("year", "rplant1", "rplant2", "rplant3", "rplant4")
dat
  year rplant1 rplant2 rplant3 rplant4
1 1950   -0.72    0.22    0.25    0.35
2 1951   -0.55    0.47    0.12    0.33
3 1952   -0.61    0.43    0.13    0.24
4 1953   -0.39    0.29    0.15    0.36
```

In which "year" is the mid-point of the 11 year moving window.  I look forward to your suggestions!

Comment: You're not worried about the future predicting the present?

Comment: My goal isn't prediction.  I just want to look for trends in the correlation over time.

Comment: If you want an answer you should post an example that can support the sort of operation requested. You don't need to have a dataset that supports 31 period window but certainly you would need more than 3 periods.

Comment: Edited to provide a reproducible example